# how to set tabhost on top of the content

Tags: android, listview, tabbar

Hy everyone
i am using TabHost to create TabBar in android....

```
    public class TabBarActivity extends TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        Intent intent;

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, CustomizedListView.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Clubs").setIndicator("Clubs", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.clubs_icon))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Events.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Events").setIndicator("Events", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.events_icon))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);



        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Maps.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Maps").setIndicator("Maps", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.maps_icon))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Settings.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Settings").setIndicator("Settings", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.settings_icon))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        getTabHost().setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inside the new tab ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //getTabHost().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
}

**tab.xml**
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TabWidget
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:id="@android:id/tabs">
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent">
            </FrameLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TabHost>
```

but the problem is that whenever the contents of the tab grow e.g displaying dynamic content in listview against a tab then the TabHost becomes INVISIBLE..

any help in this regard will be highly appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

Insted of using TabActivity use normal Activity. and then create TabHost with the tabspec based on your requirement. and add that tabHost as your first component in the screen/Activity.

Comment: can u please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679575/android-layout-on-top-of-tabs?rq=1) link????? That is exactly what i m trying to ask